# Most kind and polite way to refuse wedding invitation

Tags: work-environment, colleagues

My supervisor/project coordinator is going to get married soon and she has passed me the invitation. However I don't like weddings and I don't think we are close enough to attend such social organisation. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: The answer should be to handle this polite decline the same way you would as if the bride/groom was not in your employment chain (i.e. simply a friend/associate). Are you asking how to handle ANY non-familial invitation? There is a proposed [ettiquette.se](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86480/etiquette) in Area51, and if it were in beta I would recommend migration, but...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### How would you politely turn down the invitation if they weren't a colleague?

There is no difference between this situation and receiving an unwanted invitation from another source. Depending on your culture, an acceptable response could be **a grateful written reply, apologising for not being able to attend**. Treat the invitation as a personal matter rather than a professional one, and if possible direct your response privately rather than via the workplace.

Answer (score 31):

Personally when I was in a similar situation I sent the couple a card and a gift. I thanked the person who invited me and told them I wasn't able to attend because of other commitments.

If you aren't that close to your boss I doubt very much she will feel slighted if you don't attend. How many other people in the office have also received such an invitation? When I got married my wife gave an evening invitation to everyone in her office, we weren't offended that not everyone came.

Comment: We are not very close actually and this is a reason. If it was friend or so, I will go there in any case. Moreover she gave invitations everybody in the office and that means possibly 15-20 people got invited.

Comment: I think in the case of a blanket invite there is very little chance she'd be offended by anyone declining to attend.